# Two-stage MOSFET operational amplifier

Tags: amplifier

I've recently done a Lab at the Uni to make a Mosfet 2 stage op-amp shown in the image below:

[image]

A lot of simulations were done to understand how the op-amp worked, and whether it works correctly. Such as DC analysis, AC analysis, finding a suitable Rc, common mode range, worst case offset, etc, which I have already completed in my report.

The lab has an additional bonus component (which I always attempt, but this one seems a bit hard). It asks us to consider the above circuit as low voltage where the MOSFET transistors cannot exceed 1.8V all around, Vdd is 1.8V (max) and is single supply. In the optional component it says the above circuit must be used as a buffer which has a ground to 10V supply and must be able to ideally output 0-10V hence, the input must be between 0-10V. "Higher" voltage MOSFET transistors must be used to replace some of the lower voltage transistors along with other optional components. I am to write a page length of what the best approach is to changing the circuit as little as possible with minor assumptions.

The question seems kind of tedious and hard to comprehend. I really have no idea how to begin here as high voltage op-amps aren't even covered in lectures or even low voltage operational amplifier for that matter. The only things that I could think of is voltage sensitive devices such as current source? Obviously the transistors themselves.

Q: I'm not looking for someone to answer this, but any input to articles with similar design problems is appreciated!

Comment: If Vdd is max 1.8v, I don't see how you can ever get a 10V output. Did you mean Vds is 1.8v max?

Comment: I'm guessing Vds,Vgs,Vdg=1.8V for the original transistors derived from Vdd=1.8V for the original amp. The question is presumably: which transistors must be uprated, and which can remain in the original process, and why? A starting point is, identify which circuit nodes may have restricted voltage ranges, and which need the full swing? This leads naturally to the answer.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Hey Brian, thanks for the detailed answer. One question, if I wanted to apply 10v to the input to get a 10v output would that mean the transistors at the input would also need to be uprated? or would there be a way around this to change as few transistors as possible?

Comment: I suspect you're thinking along the right lines. Because it's called a "buffer" which implies unity gain, I can see no satisfactory way round upgrading the input transistors, nor *some* of the transistors around them. If you come up with a solution, you can answer your own question.